# Porting eCos to i386

Tags: c, linux, porting, rtos, ecos

I am trying to port eCos on an i386 PC.

I have downloaded prebuilt redboot.bin from 
http://ecos.sourceware.org/ecos/boards/redbootbins/x86pc/

I boot it onto usb disk, using 
dd conv=sync if/redboot.bin of=/dev/sdb1

After booting target from usb, I get "IA2!" string on the target monitor **always**, and on serial port on 38400 8n1 configurations, I receive **nothing**.

I tried using i386-elf-gdb, but it is not able to connect to the target and starts printing "Ignoring error packet, Continuing..."

I also tried to build redboot using configtool for i386, but it is only able to build library, when I try Tests, It gives ERROR: multiple definition of cyg_start()

I am very new to eCos, and I don't know what I am doing wrong!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to boot Redboot on a target i386 pc with RealteK RTL8139 ehternet card.

1. install grub on usb stick,

   `mkdir /mnt/USB && mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/USB`

   `grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdx`
2. Build Redboot using ecosconfig, make sure the number of pci bus are less than 8 or more, if more, then need to increase the pci bus range from from 8 inside pci.h, I had my realtek ethernet card on bus 10 dev 10, I had to increase the bus to 11, so that redboot finds realtek card on bootup.

   `ecosconfig new pc redboot`

   `configtool ecos.ecc`

   `add common ethernet support`

   `Build Library`
3. copy redboot.elf on usb.
4. on grub startup menu,

   `insmod multiboot`

   `multiboot /redboot.elf`

   `boot`

Thats it, redboot will use BOOTP and provide IP Address, then I can test redboot commands like ip_address, reset, ping, version etc.